# Communicating with background app through google assistant

Tags: android, actions-on-google, android-slices

I am doing a demo to let the user "talk with" the app without bringing the app to the foreground, but I am not sure how to do that. [Slices](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/slices) can finish the job without opening the app, but Google assistant won't read information from the slices. [Read it](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/read-it) requires the user to open the app first, although the reading can be finished in the background.

I am wondering if there is a way for the user to say "get my information from myApp" (the user is not currently in myApp), then google assistant just responds with an answer by reading it, not popping it up.

Answer (score 0):

What you described sounds more like a Conversational Action(CA). Why not implement it this way?

If you still want your Android App to handle it instead, at the moment, you'll need to implement it two steps:

1. Use GET_THING App Action to search in your app.
2. Then, use [Read it](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/read-it) to read its content.

If you feel these options don't provide what you're looking for, I encourage you to submit your use case via our [public issue tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=617864&template=1261453), providing as much detail as possible.